ggplot time series geom_line showing as a bar chart
I am trying to create a time series line chart with ggplot2 using the following code:
ggplot(my_data, aes(Period_end_date, Value, group = `Policy Year`, colour = `Policy Year`)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal()

Instead of getting a line chart I am getting a bar chart.

The policy year is a factor, the period_end_date is a date and the value is numerical.
print(my_data)
# A tibble: 1,000,193 × 16
`Policy Year` `Row Labels` Period_end_date Value `Claim status` Location `Rule Number` `Single Rule 
 <fct>         <chr>        <date>          <dbl> <chr>          <chr>    <chr>         <chr>               
1 2017          243719/01    2017-03-20       1000 CLOSED         Croatia  3.8.2         3.8.2               
2 2017          243719/01    2017-04-20       1000 CLOSED         Croatia  3.8.2         3.8.2               
3 2017          243719/01    2017-05-20       1000 CLOSED         Croatia  3.8.2         3.8.2    

Any help always appreciated.
I have tried playing about with the data types but not getting anywhere.

Are all of the “period end dates” unique?  I suspect there are duplicate values causing the lines to be drawn vertically thus looking like a bar chart. You may need to group on a different variable, like country.

Welcome to SO.  Whilst we can see some of your data (that's helpful: thank you), we can't easily use it.  Please edit your question to include the output from dput(my_data) (or dput(head(my_data)) if my_data is large).  Also, please ensure that the data you provide allows us to reproduce your problem.

Thanks, I need to group by the policy year as I want to see how one policy year develops compared to the others, I am trying to get the total value of all claims for each month. The Period end dates are not unique but are unique for each claim within the dataset if that makes sense. There are thousands of claims in the dataset and a separate row for each development month for each claim.

Thanks Limey, first post so learning :-) The dput output is too large to post in here (even with the head version), copied an exert from it below....hopefully that is enough... dput(head(my_data))
structure(list(Policy Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L), levels = c("2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"
), class = "factor") ........Period_end_date = structure(c(17245,
17276, 17306, 17337, 17367, 17398), class = "Date"), Value = c(1000,
1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)

You need to try using aes(Period_end_date, Value, group = claim, colour = Policy Year).  As it is, having non-unique end dates will not work.

I can see how you might get results like that it your data looked like this:
library(tidyverse)

my_data <- tribble (
  ~`Policy Year`, ~`Row Labels`, ~Period_end_date, ~Value, ~`Claim status`, ~Location, ~`Rule Mumber`,
  2023, "243719/01", "2024-01-01", 0, "Open", "Croatia", "3.8.2",
  2023, "243719/01", "2024-01-01", 2000, "Open", "Croatia", "3.8.2",
  2023, "243719/01", "2024-01-01", 0, "Open", "Slovakia", "3.8.2",
  
  2023, "243719/01", "2024-02-01", 0, "Open", "Croatia", "3.8.2",
  2023, "243719/01", "2024-02-01", 3000, "Open", "Croatia", "3.8.2",
  2023, "243719/01", "2024-02-01", 0, "Open", "Slovakia", "3.8.2",
  
  2024, "243719/01", "2024-01-01", 0, "Open", "Croatia", "3.8.2",
  2024, "243719/01", "2024-01-01", 1000, "Open", "Croatia", "3.8.2",
  2024, "243719/01", "2024-01-01", 0, "Open", "Slovakia", "3.8.2",
  
  2024, "243719/01", "2024-02-01", 0, "Open", "Croatia", "3.8.2",
  2024, "243719/01", "2024-02-01", 2000, "Open", "Croatia", "3.8.2",
  2024, "243719/01", "2024-02-01", 0, "Open", "Slovakia", "3.8.2",
  
) %>% 
  mutate(Period_end_date = as.Date(Period_end_date),
         `Policy Year` = as.factor(`Policy Year`)
         ) 

ggplot(my_data, aes(Period_end_date, Value, group = `Policy Year`, colour = `Policy Year`)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal()

First thing I'd try is to facet wrap by location:
ggplot(my_data, aes(Period_end_date, Value, group = `Policy Year`, colour = `Policy Year`)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(~Location)


Thank you, that does break things out nicely between locations but still shows as  a bar as opposed to a line, must be something with the data as all suggestions seem to return to the same issue. Thank you for responding though
